# Using Linq to select table items where they match a list

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have a dictionary of 'string, DeviceInfo' where DeviceInfo is a class containing a few properties as shown below:

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool Actioned { get; set; }
```

I need to use Linq to Entities to select device details from a table where the deviceId in the table exists in the  DeviceInfo “Name” property in the dictionary. Something like the following is what I’m after. Unfortunately my code doesn’t work. Anyone show me where I’m going wrong?

```
from t in _context.Devices where list.Select(x => x.Value.Name).Contains(t.DeviceId) select t
```

Comment: Have you tried with `.Contains("" + t.DeviceId)`? I'm not sure if it would work like that, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get simple `List<string>` with `Name`s from dictionary:

```
var names = list.Select(x => x.Value.Name).ToList();
```

And then use it within your LINQ to Entities query:

```
from t in _context.Devices
where names.Contains(t.DeviceId)
select t
```

Or with `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` if your `DeviceId` is and `int`:

```
from t in _context.Devices
where names.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)t.DeviceId))
select t
```

It should generate `IN` statement into SQL query.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for that. I did try putting the names in to a separate list but obviously got the second bit of linq wrong, as your solution works fine. Saved me a lot of time, thanks again.

Comment: I found that I could get away with not having to use “ToList” on the names list which hopefully will improve performance.

Comment: @Retrocoder Yes, you can omit `ToList()` but I wouldn't do it, because that will differ sql query execution and will make breaking the query possible in other methods. You could try `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToList()` to get deffered execution with sql query safety.